# Configuring Sentry handler for Django with new sentry_sdk without raven

Tags: django, sentry, raven

The new sentry_sdk for django provides very brief installation (with intergration via raven marked for deprecation).

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
  dsn="https://<key>@sentry.io/<project>",
  integrations=[DjangoIntegration()]
)
```

Previously, one would configure sentry with raven as the handler class like this.

```
'handlers': {
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'ERROR', # To capture more than ERROR, change to WARNING, INFO, etc.
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        'tags': {'custom-tag': 'x'},
    },
...
...
'loggers':{
       'project.custom':{
             'level': 'DEBUG',
             'handlers': ['sentry', 'console', ,]
       }
```

See more [as defined here](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/#django)

The challenge is that raven does not accept the new format of the SENTRY_DSN. in the format `https://<key>@domain.com/project/` The old format is along the lines of `https://<key>:<secret>@domain.com/project`. 
Raven will throw `InvalidDSN with the old format`. The old DSN Key is marked for deprecation.

The documentation is very silent on how to define handlers. and clearly raven which has been deprecated is not happy with the new key format.
I could rely on the old DSN `deprecated format` but will appreciate advice on how to configure the handler with the new format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken some reading and practicing. The new version does not depend on raven in any way. So you have to remove all references to `raven`. in `settings.py` and any references to the raven client.

There is no need to worry about the handler for sentry_sdk.
It will suffice to declare the handler for the console only and append that handler to every other logger defined as required.

```
'handlers':{
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    }
    # No need to define a sentry handler, defined by the integration.
}
'loggers':{
   'project.custom': {
       'level': 'DEBUG',
       'handlers': ['console', ], # You dont have to add sentry handler here
   }
}
```

<s>Also NOTE that `logger.exception` will just be ignored, you will have to use 
`capture_exception from sentry_sdk or capture_message from sentry_sdk`</s>

**Apparently, it is possible that an event is not logged into sentry for a number of reasons, however logger.exception should always work**

Comment: >logger.exception will just be ignored

This should not be true. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: @Markus Unterwaditzer, it should not be the case. From what I saw, logger.exception was not sending things through to sentry. It could be some other setting on my settings but with the raven handler what i saw was reports did not come to sentry with logger.exception

Comment: Yes, okay, but what about the new SDK?

Comment: As I said in my answer @MarkusUnterwaditzer if I wanted logs to be sent to sentry. I had to use `capture_exception` instead of `logger.exception`. That is if I configured it the new way `without raven`

Comment: Please report this as a bug here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python This is not expected behavior

Comment: Okay, @MarkusUnterwaditzer, let me re-produce in a pristine environment and report the bug.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer, here is the link to the issue. In there you can find a repo to the demo. Best regards.

Comment: I assume you meant to link to https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/480